# Determine position of ith element in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector: `a<-rep(sample(1:5,20, replace=T))`

I determine the frequency of occurrence of each value:

```
tabulate(a)
```

I would now like to determine the position of the most frequently occurring values.

Let's say the vector is:

```
[1] 3 3 3 5 2 2 4 1 4 2 5 1 2 1 3 1 3 2 5 1
```

tabulate returns:

```
[1] 5 5 5 2 3
```

Now I determine the highest value returned by tabulate `max(tabulate(a))`

this returns

```
[1] 5
```

There are 3 values with frequency 5. I would like to know the position of these values in the tabulate output.

i.e. I the first three entries of tabulate.

Comment: Please make an effort with your title. *Determine position of ith element in vector* should be a one-letter answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to work with `table`:

```
x <- table(a)
x
# a
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 5 5 5 2 3 
names(x)[x == max(x)]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
which(a %in% names(x)[x == max(x)])
# [1]  1  2  3  5  6  8 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20
```

Alternatively, there's a similar approach with `tabulate`:

```
x <- tabulate(a)
sort(unique(a))[x == max(x)]
```

Here are some benchmarks on numeric and character vectors. The difference in performance is more noticeable with numeric data.

***Sample data***

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(20, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(letters, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
```

***Functions to benchmark***

```
t1 <- function() {
  x <- table(a)
  out1 <- names(x)[x == max(x)]
  out1
}

t2 <- function() {
  x <- tabulate(a)
  out2 <- sort(unique(a))[x == max(x)]
  out2
}

t3 <- function() {
  x <- table(b)
  out3 <- names(x)[x == max(x)]
  out3
}

t4 <- function() {
  x <- tabulate(factor(b))
  out4 <- sort(unique(b))[x == max(x)]
  out4
}
```

***The results***

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(t1(), t2(), t3(), t4(), replications =  50)
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 t1()           50  30.548   24.244    30.416    0.064          0         0
# 2 t2()           50   1.260    1.000     1.240    0.016          0         0
# 3 t3()           50   8.919    7.079     8.740    0.160          0         0
# 4 t4()           50   5.680    4.508     5.564    0.100          0         0
```

Comment: yes the first one which outputs "1" "2" "3" is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I can accept your answer if you are pointing out that I didn't mention that I want to avoid table. But I also welcome any help if you have any ideas how to avoid it.

Comment: Are all of your values in your actual data positive? What's the range? try: `x <- tabulate(a, nbins=max(a)); which(x == max(x))`, but I really have more experience with `table` than `tabulate`.

Comment: tabulate produces NA's whenever there is a 0 in its output. say a<-c(2,2,2,3,3,3); x<-tabulate(a); sort(unique(a))[x==max(x)] produces NA. any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: @user2733997, did you see my previous comment?